Gnome-shell create alot of threads and using alot of RAM
Results of htop:

I have tried:

Restart GNOME Shell.

ALT + F2 -> r -> Enter
Still the same.

Disable all extensions.
gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com   
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com   
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com  


Shutdown the computer.

kill these threads.
pkill -f gnome-shell    
kill <pid>



After few seconds, it restart with tons of threads.
5.
reset config
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
6.
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Information

An autostart file that open a terminal
cat ~/.config/autostart/open_terminal.desktop  

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/media/hlajungo/D/linux/repo/CPE_Previous_Questions
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Open Terminal in Directory
Comment=Open terminal and navigate to a specific directory on startup


$ journalctl -b | grep gnome-shell


十一 17 11:46:52 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 dbus-daemon[10896]: [session uid=1000 pid=10896] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.131' (uid=1000 pid=15059 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
十一 17 11:46:53 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
十一 17 11:47:02 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 dbus-daemon[10896]: [session uid=1000 pid=10896] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.146' (uid=1000 pid=17752 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
十一 17 11:47:02 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
十一 17 11:47:02 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.6
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 dbus-daemon[10896]: [session uid=1000 pid=10896] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.131' (uid=1000 pid=15059 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
十一 17 11:47:21 hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 gnome-shell[15059]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).


$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.9


$ uname -a
Linux hlajungo-Predator-PH317-56 6.8.0-48-generic #48~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  7 11:24:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 



Somethings I did before this happened
I use a simple shell script to turn off the screen:
$ cat /home/hlajungo/scripts/closescreen
#!/bin/bash
xset dpms force off

Last night, I was using YouTube Music before going to sleep, so I used this script to turn off the screen while letting the music continue playing.
I also added HandleLidSwitch=ignore to /etc/systemd/logind.conf, which prevents the screen from turning off when I close the laptop.
However, after waiting until early this morning, this issue occurred.

Memory leaks in GNOME is a well-knows phenomena which has been partially addressed in recent versions. If you have limited memory, then either try a later version of Ubuntu (e.g. 24.04 or 24.10) which has a later version of GNOME, or switch out to a different lightweight desktop environment, like XFCE, MATE or LxQt

I don't think the problem exists, it's a result of my misunderstanding of htop. It only uses 230MB of RAM (by top -b -n1 | grep gnome-shell ), thanks for the response and the syntax fix. This has nothing to do with a memory leak, it's just me being stupid.
